# Телеграм бот заменяет пробелы в шэринг ссылке на %20, как менять обратно?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, url

У меня в телеграм боте есть возможность пошэрить ссылку на бота с текстом, который я прописал заранее.

в коде ссылка прописана вот так: "https://t.me/share/url?url=https://t.me/magicballgame_bot?start={tg_id}&text=Узнай свою судьбу, задав вопрос Магическому Шару!"

и в этом случае, пользователь, которому отправляется ссылка, также должен получать текст : Узнай свою судьбу, задав вопрос Магическому Шару!

но почему то, при нажатии на кнопку "поделиться", телеграм меняет пробелы на %20 и получатель вместе со ссылкой на бота получает текст Узнай%20свою%20судьбу,%20задав%20вопрос%20Магическому%20Шару!

как мне сделать так, чтобы вместо %20 были пробелы в итоговом текст, который получает пользователь, когда с ним поделились?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Коротко: никак.

Если чуть подробнее: пробелы не допустимы в ссылках. Первый же пробел в ссылке будет распознан как ее окончание. Поэтому пробелы и другие недопустимые символы заменяются на коды с %
В вашем случае надо либо смириться с этим, либо оформлять ссылку как-то под другому. Например, указывая отдельно URL и отдельно текст, который собственно будет активной ссылкой.

Comment: Странно, у нас сначала получилось и все работало верно, потом начались какие то проблемы и почему стали добавляться символы.

При чем если в браузерную строку вставить с пробелами, то все работает ок

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение! Я просто вставил ссылку "https://t.me/share/url?url=https://t.me/magicballgame_bot?start={tg_id}&text=Узнай свою судьбу, задав вопрос Магическому Шару!" в браузер, браузер перекодировал кириллицу и все стало нормально работать, пробелы находятся на своем месте

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).